# javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.focusLost(...) implementation in JDK 8_60

Tags: java, swing, focus, jbutton, action

I've noticed a strange change in the **BasicButtonListener** from JDK_1.6.0_17 -> JDK_1.8.0_60. The method **focusLost(...)** is now calling         **model.setPressed(false);** before **model.setArmed(false);**
If you press the mouse on a button and type the TAB-Key, the focusLost event causes the button to perform the action.
Now you can combine this bahavour with any situation like - you enter a text and a focusLost of the text-component causes a dialog to appear (validation or something) while you want to press a button (save for example). In that case the button would be triggered. (This is only a fictional example so please don't talk about how bad this implementation concept is ;)
In one case, the entire focus-sub-system went down, I call it that way, because the entire application had no focus at all.
Swing Focus logging showed: Peer request failed
I haven't found any useful clues regarding the problem, so I'm posting it here. Please reply if you know more regarding that change/problem.
My workaround for now is to change back the order of those two methods.
PS.: Someone wrote it's a problem on Windows OS only but not on Linux. I can't verify that, because I have only Win10@Work.
[Here is the diff of that method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP3Ek.png)

Comment: This seems like the same issue here: [JDK-8049069 JButton incorrect behaviour on button release - Java Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049069)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is exactly the same problem! Regards!